# Show notification/modal using function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, antd

I am using components `Modal` and `Notification` to show modal and notifications. The approach I am currently using is that I render e.g. `Notification` component in my top level component i.e. `App.js`. Whenever I need to show notification or confirmation Dialog I dispatch action from any component which updates redux state and Notification is shown.

What I want to implement is to show my notification or modal by just invoking a function like in antd [Notification](https://ant.design/components/notification/), [message](https://ant.design/components/message/#components-message-demo-other) and [Modal](https://ant.design/components/modal/#components-modal-demo-info).

I want to implement functions like implemented in the antd so that my notifications/modal can be shown this way:

```
notification.error('My message')
modal.confirm({content: 'xyz'})
```

Please guide me how can I render a component to show notification or modal by function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redux in this scenerio. I implemented like this

- dispatch an action `dispatch( {type : "SHOW_MODAL" , "Some Title"})`
- maintain a variable in reducer `{( modalState : randomValue())}`
- Create a Modal File which will listen to the `modalState` Variable of store
- whenever the value changes show your modal with local state
- now if you need to show the modal just dispatch a new action

Comment: any resource or example will be of great help @Mohammad Faisal.